# Applescript help to open specific pages from separate PDFs in same or different window, via their URL or UUID?

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf

I use a database app called DEVONthink (DT), which stores PDF files.  I could use a hand writing a little script which is already partially written.  Its use-case is to activate DT, then bring-to-front a specific page from a multi-page PDF document, via what DT calls a "page link." (These are essentially non-website URLs).  Below is a simple script that *almost* accomplishes what I am trying to do:

```
on run {input}
    --set input to "http://macscripter.net"
    tell application id "DNtp"
        activate
        open tab for URL (input as string)
    end tell
    --return input
end run
```

The above script (written by somebody else) works like so: if the text of a DT "page link" was manually highlighted, a keyboard shortcut could launch this little script to boot DT and present the specific page of a multi-page document. FWIW, these page links look like so:

```
x-devonthink-item://E269E475-F33E-4DE6-8513-041F69EAB3FF?page=388
```

**The modification I seek, is to simply jam the "page link" into that script** so that the script is written/saved *specifically* to show a page (in a multi-page PDF) without clicking or highlighting the page link.  Anyone know how to do this?

Icing on the cake would be to also learn how to have multiple pages from separate PDF documents launch in the same viewer window, as tabs--but that's not critical to figure out at this time.

Thank you in advance!  (I am trying to learn AppleScript--still a newbie at it (or any code)--you guys on here are terrific!

Comment: What version of **DEVONthink**, and version of **macOS** are you using?

Comment: DT version 3.6.2 on Big Sur 11.2.1.  Thanks for any guidance you might have!

Comment: Okay, I've installed **DEVONthink** on **macOS Big Sur** and played with it a bit. Can you please clarify what you are wanting here by: "**The modification I seek, is to simply jam the "page link" into that script** so that the script is written/saved specifically to show a page (in a multi-page PDF) without clicking or highlighting the page link."

Comment: Also just an FYI... There _window_ the **PDF** opens in, the **New Tab** _command_ is grayed out. Not sure it that's because that type of _window_ doesn't support multiple _tabs_ or because it's an unregistered version of **DEVONthink**.  Additionally, when using a **URL** for the page of the **PDF** it's a _zero based index_ meaning if your want e.g. page 10 the **URL** would end in: `?page=9`

Comment: @user3439894 Not certain whether it's relevant here (as I use v2) but there is an 'enable tabbed browsing' preference (under general) which I believe is required. Registration isn't likely an issue for this feature. You may also find some additional details in the DT forum… https://discourse.devontechnologies.com/t/script-to-launch-pdf-pages-from-their-page-url-from-external-software/62361/3

Comment: @Mockman, **[√] Enable tabbed browsing** is checked by default.

Comment: Then I suspect it is not relevant :)

Comment: @Ryan, did you get any answers from the DEVONtechnologies forum (Discourse)?

Comment: @jstarek Hi there. I did indeed.  There is a linked/downloadable script in the following thread, provided by Jim: https://discourse.devontechnologies.com/t/open-link-in-devonthink-pro/19492

Comment: @user3439894 I want to apologize for not seeing this until now-- *especially* in lieu of the fact that you downloaded DT for the intent purpose of lending a hand.  Thanks also for the help this past weekend. Jean_JD miraculously figured out how to inoculate that directory on my desktop, which had been stuck there for years!